# open html file on button click in Ext-JS4

Tags: extjs

I am running a html file in which when I click the submit button a new html file should open.

This is the code:
code running in loginForm.html

```
{
    xtype : 'button',
    text : ' Login ',
    formBind : true,
    listeners : {
        click :function(){ 
            alert();
            //these methods are not working
            //Ext.getCmp('login_panel').load({url : '/smartNav/pub/html/index_dev.html', scripts : true});
            //Ext.getCmp('login_panel').update('index_dev.html');

        }   
    }
}
```

Can someone suggest me how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open new window just using **window.open**

```
window.open('/smartNav/pub/html/index_dev.html');
```

or change **location** in current window

```
window.location.href='/smartNav/pub/html/index_dev.html';
```